# default property return undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating a little jQuery plugin,

I maked a object with default properties and on the init method i use $.extend for mixin this with the custom config. I want to have some default methods that could be replaced for custom methods. The thing is, If i create the "defaultConfig" as a property of the prototype the methods return *undefined*, but if I create this object into a method this return the functions good. Why it happens? Is not possible asign methods like that?

This is my code :

```
_defaultConfig:{
        'preCarga':this._defaultPrecarga,
        'onLoadArchivo':this._defaultOnload,
        'postCarga':null,

        'multiple':false,
        'name': "_jcargaArchivo"
    },
    init:function(){
        var defaultConfig ={
            'preCarga':this._defaultPrecarga,
            'onLoadArchivo':this._defaultOnload,
            'postCarga':null,
            'multiple':false,
            'name': "_jcargaArchivo"
        } ;
        /**
          This console print the methods good
         */
        console.log("init",defaultConfig);
        /**
         this._defaultConfig print "undefined in "preCarga"
          and "postCarga" properties.
         */
        console.log(this._defaultConfig,this.configuracion);
        this._configuracion = $.extend(this._defaultConfig,this.configuracion);


    },
_defaultPrecarga:function(){/*code here*/},
_defaultPostCarga:function(){/*code here*/}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't refer to another property of `this` in the object literal that's creating all the properties. You need to do it after the properties are created.

```
var default = {
    _defaultConfig:{
            'postCarga':null,
            'multiple':false,
            'name': "_jcargaArchivo"
        },
        init:function(){
            var defaultConfig ={
                'preCarga':this._defaultPrecarga,
                'onLoadArchivo':this._defaultOnload,
                'postCarga':null,
                'multiple':false,
                'name': "_jcargaArchivo"
            } ;
            /**
              This console print the methods good
             */
            console.log("init",defaultConfig);
            /**
             this._defaultConfig print "undefined in "preCarga"
              and "postCarga" properties.
             */
            console.log(this._defaultConfig,this.configuracion);
            this._configuracion = $.extend(this._defaultConfig,this.configuracion);


        },
    _defaultPrecarga:function(){/*code here*/},
    _defaultPostCarga:function(){/*code here*/}
};
default._defaultConfig.preCarga = this._defaultPrecarga;
default._defaultConfig.onLoadArchivo = this._dfaultOnLoad;
```

Another way that this is often done is by defining named functions outside the object literal, and then referring to those function names rather than using `this.functionName`.

Comment: Ok @barmar understood.